# How to Update models field based on another field of same models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, locust

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
   purchase_order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  
   purchase_order_number = models.CharField(unique=True)
   vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor)
```

i am creating Purchase Order(po) table. when po created i have to update `purchase_order_number` as "PO0"+`purchase_order_id` ex PO0123 (123 is Primary key). so i am using def save in models to accomplish this

```
def save(self):
    if self.purchase_order_id is not None:
        self.purchase_order_number = "PO"+str(self.purchase_order_id)
    return super(PurchaseOrder, self).save()
```

It is working fine with single creation but when i try to create bulk of data using locust(Testing tool) its giving an error `duplicate entry for PurchseOrdernumber` Can we modify field value in models itself some thing like this

```
purchase_order_number = models.CharField(unique=True,default=("PO"+self.purchase_order_id )
```

Comment: No it will not work i am asking, is there any way like this?

Comment: problem got resolved i forgot mention here, after creating purchase-order, in success_url method i am taking purchase_order_id and modifying purchase_order_number ` "PO"+str(self.purchase_order_id)`

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't think it should work when you create multiple instances. Because as I can see from the code:

```
if self.purchase_order_id is not None:
    self.purchase_order_number = "PO"+str(self.purchase_order_id)
```

Here `purchase_order_id` will be `None` when you are creating new instance. Also, until you call `super(PurchaseOrder, self).save()`, it will not generate `purchase_order_id`, meaning `purchase_order_number` will be empty.

So, what I would recommend is to not store this information in DB. Its basically the same as `purchase_order_id` with `PO` in front of it. Instead you can use a property method to get the same value. Like this:

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
   purchase_order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   # need to remove `purchase_order_number = models.CharField(unique=True)`
   ...

   @property 
   def purchase_order_number(self):
       return "PO{}".format(self.purchase_order_id)
```

So, you can also see the `purchase_order_number` like this:

```
p = PurchaseOrder.objects.first()
p.purchase_order_number
```

Downside of this solution is that, you can't make any [query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-return-new-querysets) on the property field. But I don't think it would be necessary anyway, because you can do the same query for the `purchase_order_id`, ie `PurchaseOrder.objects.filter(purchase_order_id=1)`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, its not working .... can you tell me  whats the problem?

Comment: I think this is the best solution for this case.

Comment: @veeresh I did explain in my answer why your solution is not working, and suggested an alternative way to resolve your issue.